# Importing external JAR with NoClassDefFoundError - depedencies

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I've to use in my project a library provided as `.jar` file by another team. However, when I'm running code using this library I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError`. I've made some investigation and I know that it could be avoided if the external team will create the `jar` with all needed dependencies on the classpath (e.g. lib folder). So my understanding is that then I can import mentioned library and all needed sub-jars will be in folder lib. The questions: Am I thinking correctly? Should I ask another team to provide lib with all sub-jar dependencies? Is there any alternative for this solution without providing `jar` with all dependencies inside, which allows avoiding this kind of errors?

Comment: Do you use maven? If yes, ask them to make it a maven artifact in your organizational repository with the proper dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I'm using maven. So the problem is that this library was taken from this repository beacause of organizational reasons (cannot be hold there at the moment). So that's reason why I need temporary deal with it as external .jar imported to project :)

Comment: Get access to their sources.  Build and install the artifact on your machine.  Add artifact to your Pom.xml. Instant dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile your project with maven, then there must be all the jar files needed. If you only pick your "jar" file and execute it, it will fail, because you must include the dependencies in the classpath.

Another option is to build the jar file including all the dependencies in it.

For example, using the *maven-assembly-plugin*:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.path.to.your.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>        
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```